# Stacking certain td with css

Tags: css

I am trying to stack two td with CSS. Sample code below; I want to stack the last two cells on top of each other using css.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Billy</td>
        <td>86</td>
        <td>4.1</td>
        <td>36c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jimmy</td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>4.9</td>
        <td>88d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with CSS and tables. Either use CSS and DIV's or add `rowspan` to `td` elements:

```css
td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Billy</td>
    <td rowspan="2">86</td>
    <td>4.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>36c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Jimmy</td>
    <td rowspan="2">99</td>
    <td>4.9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Or add a new table inside the last `td` with two rows.

Comment: @ralph.m Good luck with tables hell. I have seen webpage with 10th depth table.

Comment: Yeah @Justinas, brings back memories of those HTML email days I'm happy to have left behind.

Comment: @ralph.m From my experience it was very early "responsive" design :D

Comment: Haha. I entered the scene just when CSS and web standards were taking off, so I didn't have to endure the website table layout days.